# SpringMVC Null principal when exception occured

Tags: spring, security, authentication, servlets

I'm using spring and face the problem. 
The problem is when i redirect user to the error page, it makes the principal null, but not the others pages.

Here is my config

web.xml

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/exception/status/404</location>
</error-page>
```

exception controller

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/exception/status/{code}")
    public String error(
            @PathVariable(value = "code") int code, 
         Principal principal,
            HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletRequest res, ModelMap map) {

        logger.info(JSONFactory.toJson(principal));
            logger.info(JSONFactory.toJson(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()));

        return ERROR_PAGE;
    }
```

How can i get the principal back, because the error pages need some authentication to display messages ?

Answer (score 0):

It just because the Principal object is not passed to requested page.
This is not the best practice to solve this problem. But I think you can work around with this:
You can put the Principle object to ModelMap object before redirect user to the error page and get it back in error page: `map.put("principle", principle);`

But I think you should study about [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).